# Pygame Display Position While Running

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am making a pygame project, and have an issue where the window sets itself in the corner of the screen when I back out of full screen mode. Normally, this wouldn't be an issue but it hides the toolbar off screen, making it impossible to drag the screen around or resize it. I have found `pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()` to be far to unreliable and breaks whenever I use it, so I made my own method of toggling fullscreen:

```
import pygame, tkinter

fullscr = False
scrw, srch = tkinter.Tk().winfo_screenwidth(), tkinter.Tk().winfo_screenheight()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_F11:
                if fullscr:
                    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((scrw, scrh), pygame.RESIZABLE)
                    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
                else:
                    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((980, 720), pygame.RESIZABLE)
                fullscr = not fullscr
```

For those curious, I set the window to fill the screen before setting it to fullscreen because the window will maintain its aspect ratio, breaking my game and causing weird glitches. I am already aware of `os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'` as a way to center the screen, but this does not work after running `pygame.init()`. Are there any other ways I can change the windows position, or at least prevent it from hiding the toolbar off screen when toggling out of fullscreen?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pygame 2 bug.

It's reported on github here: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2360,
and the author there realized that you can get around this for now by calling pygame.quit() and then reinitializing to have the SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED work.

Hopefully this will be fixed in pygame 2.0.2. I've written a patch for it at https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2460

Comment: Thanks, it seems like a stupid workaround but it works for the time being.